# Additive functors as colimits of representable functors

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, additive-categories

Let $A$ be an additive category. Denote $(A, Ab)$ the category of all additive functors from A to the category of abelian groups.

There is well known result that any functor $F \colon C \to Sets$ on a locally small category $C$ is a colimit of representable functors $F\cong \operatorname{colim}_I Hom(X_i, -)$, where indexing category $I$ can be taken to be opposite to the category of elements of $F$.

I'm interested in the similar statement for additive functors: is it true that any additive functor is a colimit of representable functors?

In the book "Homological Theory of Representations" by H. Krause I found the following

[image]

[image]

I have two questions about this proof.

1. Why the map in the proof is a map of abelian groups, not just sets.
2. Doesn't this lemma contradicts this discussion https://mathoverflow.net/questions/204792/is-every-abelian-group-a-colimit-of-copies-of-z for $A=\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: The cited lemma, I believe, is only claiming that there is a (natural) bijection of sets. In the first place, I do not think $\mathcal{C}_{/ F}$ is additive.

Comment: That C/F is not additive is OK, it is an indexing category. The lemma stated that colimit is taken in the category of additive functors, but the proofs works only for colimits in the category of all set-valued functors. In the former case components of natural transformations are additive maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a gap in the proof to be filled: namely, that the colimit in the category of set-valued presheaves is also the colimit in the category of additive presheaves.
For this we need to use the hypothesis that $\mathcal{C}$ itself is additive.

Suppose we have a cocone in $\textbf{Add} (\mathcal{C}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Ab})$ from $\Phi_\mathcal{C}$ to $G$.
We know from the non-additive version of the lemma that there is an induced morphism $\theta : F \to G$, thinking of $F$ and $G$ as ordinary presheaves.
It suffices to show that the components $\theta_C : F (C) \to G (C)$ are group homomorphisms.

Let $x$ and $y$ be elements of $F (C)$.
Under the canonical identification $F (C \oplus C) \cong F (C) \times F (C)$, we have an element $\langle x, y \rangle \in F (C \oplus C)$.
Explicitly, this is the unique element such that the action of the two insertions $\iota_1, \iota_2 : C \to C \oplus C$ yield $x$ and $y$ respectively.
Thus, $\theta_{C \oplus C} (\langle x, y \rangle) = \langle \theta_C (x), \theta_C (y) \rangle$, by considering the following commutative diagram:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
F (C) @>{\theta_C}>> G (C) \\
@A{F (\iota_1)}AA @AA{G (\iota_1)}A \\
F (C \oplus C) @>{\theta_{C \oplus C}}>> G (C \oplus C) \\
@V{F (\iota_2)}VV @VV{G (\iota_2)}V \\
F (C) @>>{\theta_C}> G (C)
\end{CD}$$
But we also have the diagonal $\delta : C \to C \oplus C$, whose action on $F (C \oplus C)$ sends $\langle x, y \rangle$ to $x + y$.
Hence, $\theta_C (x + y) = \theta_C (x) + \theta_C (y)$, by considering this commutative diagram:
$$\begin{CD}
F (C \oplus C) @>{\theta_{C \oplus C}}>> G (C \oplus C) \\
@V{F (\delta)}VV @VV{G (\delta)}V \\
F (C) @>>{\theta_C}> G (C)
\end{CD}$$

A similar argument shows that $\theta_C (0) = 0$.
Thus $\theta_C : F (C) \to G (C)$ is a group homomorphism, so $F$ indeed has the universal property of the colimit of $\Phi_\mathcal{C}$, in $\textbf{Add} (\mathcal{C}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Ab})$ just as much as in $[\mathcal{C}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$.

Note that the argument above is completely inapplicable when $\mathcal{C}$ is only $\textbf{Ab}$-enriched.
This is the reason why it does not contradict the fact that not every abelian group is a colimit of a diagram of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$.
There is an analogous result for the general situation where $\mathcal{C}$ is just an $\textbf{Ab}$-enriched category, but it is necessary to use weighted colimits instead of conical colimits, and ultimately it turns out to be something of a tautology.